# How Does One Create a Global Variable Repository

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes, variables

This may have a simple answer but I would like to store all the variables I've declared ( or cached ) across my theme in a central file and serve then this file globally ( Similar to how `get_header()`, `get_footer()` and `get_sidebar()` works ).

I've tried creating a file called `variables.php` and serving it via `get_template_part` but without success.

For this particular project, it would be more convenient if the multitude of variables I've created across my theme were housed in a central location in lieu of being scattered throughout various theme files.

Is there a idiomatic way of accomplishing this in WordPress?

Comment: I've removed the PHP tag as well as my question (not important) from the comments. Still: How is this specific to WordPress and not just PHP _in context_ of WP?

Comment: @kaiser The question is regarding a WordPress theme. I suppose a pure PHP solution could exist and would work but the preferred answer would be an idiomatic WordPress solution.

Comment: Just use require_once/include_once in your functions.php if it's a theme issue.

Comment: have to agree with kaiser, how you structure your code is not related to wordpress. In general of course you should have exactly zero global variable which will solve your problem, wordpress has already too many globals as it is.

Comment: You seem to describe _configuration_ file rather than "variables" one. WordPress has no configuration file concept or convention (`wp-config.php` being just a place where constant definitions are dumped) so it's up to you (and generic PHP) how to implement it.

Comment: @AndrewBartel Thanks. I just put the variables in my `functions.php` file. I didn't need `require_once` or `include_once`

Comment: @MarkKaplun True but there is a such thing as best practice. Which is what I was looking for in this case. I went with @AndrewBartel method of dropping the variables in my `functions.php` file.

Comment: @Wilhelm best practices is to use namespaces and classes or do something with the options or transients APIs.  You're not going to blow up your install with a few globals or constants but just be aware of how easily that sort of thing can get out of hand.

Comment: globals are evil, you should not use globals, it is really as simple as that. Any way you will group them they will still be evil therefor since using globals is against best practice there is no "best practice for using globals".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 'better' way of storing variables for global use is to use `add_option()` to cache variables and `get_option()` for retrieving variables. This way everything stored in the database and you can access it anywhere.